# Discord Rich Presence in AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, discord

Discord released a [Rich Presence SDK](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-rpc) that lets C++ developers integrate their game with Discord, which really is an extension of their existing [RPC server](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc) built into Discord. Lately this SDK has been ported to more and more languages, including [Java](https://github.com/PSNRigner/discord-rpc-java) and [Javascript](https://github.com/devsnek/discord-rich-presence). I know AIR can interface with Javascript, but they seem to use node.js which could be messy.

With all of these new wrappers popping up, what would be the best way of going about this for an AIR app? I'm trying to figure out the most efficient method for creating an AS3 version but I'm not sure which path is the best.

Edit: I don't even want the fancier features, I just want to be able to set a user's local Discord client to display extra game info.

Comment: Well you say it's AIR and that there is a C++ implementation. Why not use a Native Extension?

Comment: Is there a way to develop an ANE that works both for Windows and Mac? I've been having trouble finding resources on how to implement one, especially for both OS.